# Test Mobile Website on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, asp.net-4.0

I have created Mobile Website on VS2010 4.0. I want to test this on Mobile browser. I have installed Android Emulator from http://www.asp.net/mobile/device-simulators. I just want to know how can I test the application on Emulator which is hosted on local IIS(my computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `10.0.2.2` as IP for server running on the same machine as the Android Emulator.

Comment: I don't quite understand, What just happened here?  What are the steps to do this?

Comment: @Carlos what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @Praful,  I actually figured it out. I forgot you can run a web app on IIS without deploying it.  Which worked for me. A bit of a pain to try to get these things to work sometimes.  Thanks for the response.